# how does an interpreter use machine instructions?

Tags: interpreter

I have found somewhere on the net the line saying "An Interpreter is a program that implements or simulates a virtual machine using the base set of instructions of a programming language as its machine language. " In this context of the above quote,can anyone explain it as how an interpreter actually accomplish execution of the high level instructions? The tutorials found on the net deals only with abstract manner saying that it takes one line at a time and executes.Does it uses a library of machine instructions or how? I am eager to know about it.

Comment: I think your assumption must be wrong, for example if you enter python into your terminal and start typing your program, it executes every command, but for example if you want to write a for loop or and if, it just wont execute it until the block is finished.

Comment: You only speak english. I speak every human language.  We travel to twenty different non-english speaking countries. How do you speak with the people of each country?

Comment: Then there must be someone intermediary who knows both the languages,,right? @Will

Comment: Yes.  And that would be me.  You can speak to me in our common language (english), and I then translate that into a language the local understands.  You don't need to speak every language.  Nor does anybody else who speaks english.  Just talk to me, and I'll translate as needed.  The Aristocrats.

Comment: very complex!!! then how it relates(or maps) the intermediate representations with the actual machine code?? interesting!!! @Will

Comment: I write C# code.  This is compiled into Intermediate Language (IL).  The CLR (Common Language Runtime) knows IL.  There are different implementations of the CLR--one that runs on Windows, one that runs on Linux-based machines, and more are coming.  So, you're C#, I'm the CLR, and the natives are Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, etc.

Comment: Next time I have to build a CLR ;) so as to know what are inside lol @Will

Answer (score 0):

An interpreter looks at each instruction in the source code and then runs code to perform that instruction. It doesn't concern itself with machine code.

For example, if your interpreter is written in C#, and the source code says to add two to a number, the interpreter would eventually call a method that adds the numbers.

Many interpreters compile to bytecode. Bytecodes are instructions that can be executed much faster than the original source code can be parsed. So we might end up with the following bytecodes:

```
1,
7,
2
```

The interpreter defines what these number means. But we could have the first number be the instruction. In this case, the 1 means to add a number to a variable. The 7 could be an index to the variable that needs to be added to. And the 2 could be the number to be added. So your handler for the add function could look something like this:

```
if (bytecode[current] == 1)
{
    int varId = bytecode[++current];
    int value = bytecode[++current];
    Variables[varId] += value;
}
```

So the machine code is generated by the C# compiler. The interpreter code doesn't care about machine code. It just has a routine to execute the particular instruction.

This should also demonstrate why compiled code runs faster. Instead of bytecode, it would be compiled to machine code. So there is no need to call a handler at runtime. It would simple execute the instructions directly.